# How to set a global variable that can be accessed between components?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, components, global-variables

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mx3mN.png
Heres a picture of the structure of the project

In login.component.html I have code to obtain the username via user input from a standard login screen:

**Login.component.html**

```
      <form [formGroup]="loginForm" #ngForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="submitForm()" class="login-form">
        <mat-card-content>
          <p class="content">Username:<span>*</span></p>
          <input type="text" formControlName="userName" id="userName" autocomplete="off">
          <div class="form-group"  *ngIf="userError">
            <p class="alert1 alert-danger">
                <strong>Required: </strong>Username
```

that username is followed up in login.component.ts like so:

**login.component.ts**

```
.....
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm, FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('ngForm') ngForm: NgForm;

  loginForm = new FormGroup({
    userName: new FormControl(),
    userPass: new FormControl()
  });

  userError: boolean = false;
  passError: boolean = false;

  

  constructor(private router: Router, private location: Location) { }


  ngOnInit() {
    if (sessionStorage.length != 0) {
      this.location.replaceState('/tool');
      this.router.navigate(['/tool']);
    }
  }


  submitForm() {
    if ((this.loginForm.value.userPass == null && 
         this.loginForm.value.userName == null)) {
      this.userError = true;
      this.passError = true;
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.userError = false;
        this.passError = false;
      }, 4000);


......

//New Code

else {
      if (this.loginForm.value.userName != "" && this.loginForm.value.userPass != "") {
        sessionStorage.setItem(this.loginForm.value.userName, this.loginForm.value.userPass);
        localStorage.set("user", JSON.stringify(this.loginForm.value.userName)); // new code inserted here
        let userName = JSON.parse(localStorage.get("user")); //and here
        this.location.replaceState('/tool');
        this.router.navigate(['/tool']);
      }
    }
  }
```

What I'm trying to do is create a global variable that would allow me to access username from login.component.ts and interact with it in buyback.component.ts. I think I need to create a global variable for the username in the login.component.ts file within the submitForm code but I don't know how.

How can I code a global variable that would allow me to take what the user inputs as their username in login.component.html and ts file and interact with that data in buyback.component.ts alongside other variables like arbNumber, choice, buybackType, etc (that can be viewed in code below..)

**buyback.component.ts**

```
....

export class BuybackComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private _buybackService: BuybackService, private router: Router, private location: Location) { }


  userName:String; //new code
  arbNumber:String;
  arbNumber2:String;
  bType:String;
  optionValue:String;
  choice:String;
  buybackAmt:String;
  buybackTypeChoice:String

.....
```

Answer (score 1):

In Angular you have some ways to share global things. The best practice is to use a simple service. `ng g s shared-data`

The service can look like this:

```
export class SharedService {
  private userData: { userName: string, role: string };

  public getUser() {
    return this.userData;
  }

  public setUser(userData: any) {
    this.userData = userData;
  }
}
```

And in any component you can do this:

```
constructor(private sharedData: SharedData) {}

getUser() {
  this.sharedData.getUser(); // Here it is!
}
```

But the best way to save data like user name, token, role and so on can be the browser local storage:

```
localStorage.set("user", JSON.stringify(userData)); // can be a simple string, too

let user = JSON.parse(localStorage.get("user"));
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about how to apply this to my specific situation? Is ng g s shared-data a terminal command?  Should I copy and paste the service code into login.component.ts? And then use the constructor code in my buyback.component.ts file so the username thats inputted from login.component.html and directed to login.component.ts can be passed to buyback.component.ts?

Comment: Or is simply using the localStorage option in login.component.ts file feasible enough to allow buyback.component.ts to interact with the userName variabled inputted from login.component.html and passed to login.component.ts?

Comment: You can use the localStorage. The `ng g s xxx` is the terminal command by the Angular CLI. It creates a service skeleton for you. And in constructor you get the service.

Comment: And that localstorage code should be used in login.component.ts right? Is that code you have linked a general template? And where exactly in the code should it be implemented? Attempting to use it in its current state yields errors

Comment: Yes, it can be inside the login component. Inside a service.

Comment: I see. Attempting to insert the localstorage code yields an error saying "Cannot find userData" and I'm not sure why. I went ahead and reformatted my original post with more code of my login.component.ts displayed. Could you tell me where and how that localstorage code should inserted so its exactly compatible with my code?

Comment: in `onSubmit` if the user correctly signed in. Then save the data to local storage and redirect to welcome page as example. And in App.module.ts you can check (autologin) if data data available (if (this.localStorage("userData")) ...

Comment: Okay so I made some edits. If you scroll all the way down in the login.component.ts code you'll see "//new code" where I made the edits. In the SubmitForm method the username and password are checked for not being empty then submitted to localstorage to be saved as strings. Then let = userName I presume allows me to use userName variable in other components right? I added userName into the buyback.component.ts code (that was also updated above) and yet I get "'userName' is declared but its value is never read." in the buyback.component.ts file. Where am I going wrong?